# Удаление(Destroy) GameObject не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть проект на unity. Суть в том, что при подгрузки нового(второго) уровня из префаба старый(первый) уровень с тегом Level я должен удалить. Делаю я это следующим образом:

```
    GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Level");
    foreach (GameObject item in objects)
    {
        Destroy(item);
        Debug.Log("Destroy1");
    }
    objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Respawn");
    foreach (GameObject item in objects)
    {
        Destroy(item);
        Debug.Log("Destroy2");
    }
    hero.level = Instantiate(AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(string.Format("Assets/Resources/Levels/{0}lvl.prefab",hero.lvl), typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
    hero.level.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
    Debug.Log(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Level").Length);
    hero.gameObject.transform.position = GameObject.FindWithTag("Respawn").transform.position;
```

Но, в результате мой hero падает на первом уровне на старое место, ну, то есть на первый Respawn
Что делать - ума не приложу, ибо испробовал уже практически всё, что есть. Спасибо)

UPD: Ещё что хотелось бы отметить - сами объекты скрываются, то есть происходит реально ощущение, что всё удалилось, но программа так не думает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, для начала - не использовать `FindWithTag`) трудно найти что-то более ненадежное и менее производительное.

Создайте класс `GameLevel` и повесьте его на корневой объект ваших уровней. Задайте в этом классе поля со ссылками на все нужные вам на уровне вещи - например, на точку респауна (например, назовём её `RespawnPoint`).

Создайте класс `LevelManager` - путь он знает имена всех уровней и умеет их загружать и создавать в нужном месте.  Пусть у него будет поле типа `GameLevel`, и если на момент смены уровня оно не null - менеджер уничтожает объект из него, после чего загружает, создаёт и назначает в него же новый уровень, а затем спаунит героя в точке, на которую ссылается поле `RespawnPoint` текущего `GameLevel`.

Искать объекты на сцене через имя или теги нужно только в самом крайнем случае :) иначе всяческие непредвиденные ситуации будут у вас происходить довольно часто.

Comment: Шикарно, спасибо) Ещё такой вопрос - я отслеживаю изменение уровня тем, что игрок падает на полоску ниже экрана. Так вообще правильно делать?)

Comment: @piller97, Если ответ верен - пометьте его правильным. А про доп. вопрос не совсем понял) что вы имеете ввиду под "отслеживаю изменение уровня"? Мол он у вас спрыгивает в какую-то яму, там внизу стоит коллайдер, который отлавливается соприкосновение и начинает грузить новый уровень?

Comment: Именно) Мне интересно, наколько это правильно)

Comment: @piller97, да вполне нормально именно как отслеживание. Как вы потом оповещаете менеджер о том, что уровень закончился? По идее на эту "полоску" нужно повесить какой-то класс, который будет просто "Handler-ом", т.е. только отлавливать событие входа игрока в него и вызывать у себя событие об этом. А уже, например, LevelManager или сам GamaLevel будет подписываться на список этих хэндлеров при старте нового уровня. Тогда сам класс-хэндлер для чего угодно можно потом использовать - хоть для телепортирования героя при входе в зону, хоть для подкидывания вверх.